# Repeating variable length segments in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the following with this Regexp:

```js
/(?<route>(?:.*\/){1,2}?)(?<group>(?:.*\/){1,2}+)?/
```

- route/group/
- route1/route2/group/group2/
- route/group1/group2/
- route/

Tried to make the first group lazy and the second one greedy and optional but it doesn't match. What am I missing?

Initial Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aRvvQE/2

Comment: What you want to use is something like `/^(?<route>(?:[^\/]+\/){1,2})(?<group>(?:[^\/]+\/){1,2})?$/`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DvkMGg/1). Also, note that JS regex does not support possessive quantifiers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot for the help! I'm trying to understand this one fully first. It does look much better but it does not match `route/group1/group2/` correctly.

Comment: You could try [`^(?<route>(?:[^/\s]+(?:\/|$)){1,2}?)(?<group>(?:[^/\s]+(?:\/|$)){1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/mNHHs0/1), it also supports optional trailing `/`

Comment: @Hao Wu that one looks great! I'm still wrapping my head around it and integrate it in a complete URL but this seems to answer my question. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Might be a little over convoluted but you may try [`^(?<route>(?:[^/\s.]+(?:\/|$)){1,2}?)(?<group>(?:[^/\s.]+(?:\/|$)){1,2})?(?=[^\/\s]*$)(?!\w+$)`](https://regex101.com/r/mi0lIy/1) for your updated URLs

Comment: @HaoWu this one is definitely working as well! I'll be able to learn a lot from your examples, thank you so much!

Comment: You could've posted the full URLs at the beginning so it won't resolve into an XY problem :O

Comment: @HaoWu you're right, I just wanted to make sure I get this part first before moving on. Your initial answer would have already sufficed as an accepted answer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a file extension at the end of the path then you could use:

```js
(?<route>(?:[^/\s]*\/){1,2}?)(?<group>(?:[^/\s]*\/){0,2})(?=[^/]*\.)
```

If not then change `\.` to `$` or whatever suits.

Comment: This one absolutely worked even with the filename added at the end. Thanks you so much! I added a working demo in my question: https://regex101.com/r/O6GVVN/4

Comment: is there a way to ignore the `/` from the groups? so `route/` would become just `route`, but the matches stay the same?